# strange behavior of .animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am using `.animate()` to swap positions of two images

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Zh6/30/). When you switch browser tab when animation is happening it is not working properly !!!

below is a code piece that i use

```
  function swapShip(one, two) {
            var oneposition = $("#ship" + shipsArray[one]).position();
            var twoposition = $("#ship" + shipsArray[two]).position();
            $("#ship" + shipsArray[two]).animate({ "left": oneposition.left, "top": oneposition.top }, levelSpeed[level]);
            $("#ship" + shipsArray[one]).animate({ "left": twoposition.left, "top": twoposition.top }, levelSpeed[level], function () {
                ++counter;
                shuffle();
            });
        }
```

This works fine if I am in the same tab, but if i navigate to a different tab two/three images goto same position !! I have tried it N times

Comment: you mean if you're switching browser-tabs?

Comment: Yeah !! just goto some other tab when animation is going on and come back